# ignore modified and newly added files

Tags: git, gitignore

I am following [guideline](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) to keep **.gitignore** file for my project. But it still show modified and new files of that type.

Current .gitignore file contain:   `git rm -r --cached .idea/`

Anything else I need to mention to ignore of same type file. No matter if they modified or new added.

Comment: Your gitignore file should contain things like `.idea/` (one pattern per line, nothing else on that line).

Comment: right...so I wanted to ignore all file part of .idea/ directory.

Comment: If you put a line with `.idea/` into `.gitignore` then that directory and its contents will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misread the guideline.

In .gitignore, you only need to list up the files (you can use wildcard) you want to exclude, not the command as shown in your question.

Comment: Above mentioned command worked...but not for untracked and Modified files.

Comment: Above mentioned command does not ignore anything. It unstages some files.

Comment: ohh...do u have any guide/example for me to follow as per requirement.

Comment: @Shubh, what do you mean by "show modified and new files"? *--cached*  of *git rm* will only update repository index, files in you worktree will not be changes. By .gitignore, you will not show them when you use *git status* command. I think you mixed all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the content of your *.gitignore* file and add to it next lines:

```
.idea/*
.idea/
```

Please read additional details and examples of the *.gitignore* file by the following link: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore